# Centering several td in table

Tags: html, css

i'm creating a livescore row and wondering how i can center the "everton 2-3 manchester united" so that that the HYPHEN always is in the same place regardless of the row, team and score size? Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fgLeL6hx/

```
.match-table {
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid;
    height: 38px;
}

.match-icon {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
}

.match-time {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
}
```

html:

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="match-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="tr-first odd">
            <td class="match-icon" >PBL</td>

            <td class="match-home">Everton</td>
            <td class="match-score">2 - 3</td>
            <td class="match-away" >Manchester United</td>
            <td class="match-time">22:00</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: Give each `td` class a fixed/relative (relative % to table) widths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that would make the hyphen *not* appear in the same position on all rows is that the numbers on both sides of it may take different widths. (Table formatting takes care of the rest.) But this is tricky. HTML and CSS in theory allow us to align cells of a column to a specific character. In practice, this has never been implemented in any browser.

The way to handle this is to split the column containing the scores to three columns (or maybe two). Instead of `<td>12 - 0</td>` you would have `<td>12</td> <td>-</td> <td>0</td>`. Then you can style the columns as desired. The details heavily depend on the styling as a whole. In the following example, I have removed fixed widths, making the table column widths to be determined by the browser.

By the way, scores are better written with an en dash rather than a hyphen, and without spacing, e.g. 2–3 rather than 2 - 3. Small spacing may be used though. I mention this since such issues should be settled before considering the details of styling.

```css
.match-table {
    border:1px solid;
    height: 38px;
}

.match-icon {
    height: 38px;

}

.match-time {
    height: 38px;
    text-align: right;
}

td {
    padding-left: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 0.2em; 
}
td:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(5) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="match-table"><tbody>
<tr class="tr-first odd">
    <td class="match-icon" >PBL</td>
    <td class="team-home">Everton</td>
    <td>2</td> <td>-</td> <td>3</td>
    <td class="team-away bold" ><span class="padl">Manchester United<span class="racard racard1">&nbsp;</span></span></td>
    <td class="match-time">22:00</td>
   <tr class="tr-first odd">
    <td class="match-icon" >XY</td>
    <td class="team-home">Foo</td>
     <td>12</td> <td>-</td> <td>0</td>
    <td class="team-away bold" ><span class="padl">Bar<span class="racard racard1">&nbsp;</span></span></td>
    <td class="match-time">9:00</td> 
</tr>
</tbody>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this CSS:

```
table {
    margin:1em auto 1em auto;
}
td {
    text-align:center;
}
```

That will center the table on the page and the hyphen should be pretty close. It might be a few pixels off if it's something like 12-3 or 3-12 (2 letters on one side 1 letter on the other). The only way to workaround that I see would be to create another row of just the hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a text-align to your css. I added it to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fgLeL6hx/

```css
.team-home {
    text-align: center;
}
.score-bold{
    text-align: center;
}
.team-away-bold{
    text-align: center;
}
```

And never leave spaces in class or id-names.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to width, I prefer percentage.

If I understand your question, this css should help you:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqsa3m6m/)

```
.match-table {
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid;
    height: 38px;
}

.match-icon {
    width: 10%;
    height: 38px;
    text-align:left;
}

.match-time {
    width: 10%;
    height: 38px;
    text-align:right;
}

table td{
    width: 27%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

There is 5  in your table. So 100/5 = 20. We need 20% width. But first and last  does not need that space (and Manchester United does not even fit in 20% so..) I decided to give 10% width to first and last . What have we got left? 80%. 80/3 ~= 27

This will make your content width more than 100% (maybe 100.xxx I don't know) if you are not comfortable with that, you can give 26% each or decrease 10%'s.